# How to plot Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) and zero crossings for 3D data in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, plot

I have 3D dataset (X,Y,Z). I would like to perform KDE, plot the data and its estimation. Then, get the zero crossings and plot it with KDE. My attempt is below. I have the following questions:

1. line `X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]` and `positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(),Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()])`as [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) (kde documentation) will they have any effects in visualising the real estimation for the original data?.  I don't really understand why I have to use my min and max to perform KDE and then use `ravel()`?
2. why I have to transpose the data in `f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)`
3. Is the code correct ?
4. I failed to plot the original data with KDE estimation and KDE estimation/ original data with zero crossing:
5. Should zero crossings be vector ?. In the code below it's tuple

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = ',')
   Convert series from data-frame into arrays
   X = np.array(df['x']) 
   Y = np.array(df['y']) 
   Z = np.array(df['z'])
   data = np.vstack([X, Y, Z])
   # perform KDE
   kernel = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(data)
   density = kernel(data)
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
   x, y, z = data
   scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=density)
   xmin = values[0].min()
   xmax = values[0].max()
   ymin = values[1].min()
   ymax = values[1].max()
   zmin = values[2].min()
   zmax = values[2].max()
   X,Y, Z =      np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j,ymin:ymax:100j,zmin:zmax:100j]
   positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(),Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()])


   f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
   derivative = np.gradient(f)
   dz, dy, dx = derivative
   xdiff = np.sign(dx)   # along X-axis 
   ydiff = np.sign(dy)   # along Y-axis 
   zdiff = np.sign(dz)   # along Z-axis
   xcross = np.where(xdiff[:-1] != xdiff[1:])
   ycross = np.where([ydiff[:-1] != ydiff[1:]])
   zcross = np.where([zdiff[:-1] != zdiff[1:]])

   Zerocross =  xcross + ycross + zcross
   ```

Comment: 3-D data plus a density is 4-dimension in total. It's quite hard to visualize such data in a meaningful way. 2-D KDE is very easy to do (just one-liner if you use `seaborn`). Maybe consider a dimension-reduction via PCA to transform 3-D to 2-D without losing too much information.

Comment: Because `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` calculates the KDE exactly, there will never be a zero crossing (except at infinity).  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JoeKington it looks like she wants to estimate the zero-crossings of the derivative of the kernel density function

Answer (score 2):

> line `X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]` and `positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(),Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()])` as [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) (kde documentation) will they have any effects in visualising the real estimation for the original data?. I don't really understand why I have to use my `min` and `max` to perform KDE and then use `ravel()`?

Those two lines set up a grid of x, y, z locations where the KDE will be evaluated. In the code above they are only being used to estimate the derivative of the kernel density function. Since they aren't currently being used for anything related to plotting, they won't affect the visualisation.

`xmin`, `xmax` etc. are used to ensure that the grid covers the full range of x, y, z values in your data. The syntax `xmin:xmax:100j` does the equivalent of `np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)`, i.e. [`np.mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) returns 100 evenly spaced points between `xmin` and `xmax`.

The `X`, `Y` and `Z` arrays returned by `np.mgrid` will each have shapes `(100, 100, 100)`, whereas the `positions` argument to `kernel(positions)` needs to be `(n_dimensions, n_points)`. The line `np.vstack([X.ravel(),Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()])` just reshapes the output of `np.mgrid` into this form. [`.ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) flattens each `(100, 100, 100)` array into a `(1000000,)` vector, and [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) concatenates them over the first dimension to make a `(3, 1000000)` array of points.

> why I have to transpose the data in `f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)`

You don't :-). The output of `kernel(positions)` is a 1D vector, so transposing it will have no effect.

> I failed to plot the original data with KDE estimation and KDE estimation/ original data with zero crossing:

What did you try? The code above seems to estimate zero-crossings of the gradient of the kernel density function, but doesn't include any code to plot them. What sort of a plot do you want to make?

> Should zero crossings be vector ?. In the code below it's tuple

When you call [`np.where(x)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) where `x` is a multidimensional array, you get back a tuple containing the indices where `x` is non-zero. Since `xdiff[:-1] != xdiff[1:]` is a 3D array, you will get back a tuple containing three 1D arrays of indices, one per dimension.

You probably don't want the extra set of square brackets in `np.where([ydiff[:-1] != ydiff[1:]])`, since in that case `[ydiff[:-1] != ydiff[1:]]` will be treated as a `(1, 100, 100, 100)` array rather than `(100, 100, 100)`, and you'll therefore get a tuple containing 4 arrays of indices rather than 3 (the first one will be all zeros, since the size in the first dimension is 1).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. But as you have mentioned that the grid is used in the derivative, 1) Does this affect getting the correct zero crossings for the derivative of the original data ?. I plot KDE result in scatter(x, y, z, c=density). However, 2) I don't know the best way to show the flow; plot original data with KDE, show first derivative and also the zero-crossings (peaks), Can you give me any guidance on how to show changes from original data until zero crossing to show the peaks?. 3) If I want to get the number of zero crossing, should it be only len(Zerocross)?.

Comment: Also, 4) How does 100j or 50j step affect the first derivative?. When I plot scatter for both of them. The points are on the same places on X, and Y axis, but their densities values are slightly changed.